# How can I hook my Ubuntu laptop through HDMI into a TV as a second monitor, but only use the speakers on the TV?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, lg

I have a laptop that is hooked up to a very large TV as a second monitor and everything works just perfectly, the problem is I use the TV to play music in the background while I work on my laptop. This is great and all, except the TV is LCD and I'm worried about burn-in. Is there a way to make the part of the desktop on the TV blank so no images burn into it while I'm on it for a long time?

EDIT: I guess I'm not being very clear. I know exactly how to make my tv act as a second monitor and play sound through it, the problem is I can't leave it plugged into my tv for long because the image will burn into it. Is there any way to have a screensaver of a fullscreen moving image on just one screen to avoid such burn-in?

Answer (score 0):

No worries: LCD does not experience burn-in. Plasma displays will experience burn-in, but not LCD.

Another option would be to run audio cables into the TV when you are not using it as a display.

Comment: 1. It must not be LCD, but I just used it and left a youtube video up on it and when I moved the Youtube window, the youtube logo was a little burned in.  2. I use an HDMI cord, but I don't have any other way to connect it to the TV. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Being the owner of a plasma TV, I can appreciate the sensitivity to this issue. If you can see any burn-in, especially on pure white backgrounds, you might try playing [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4gE_Xez-fQ) in full screen 720p on the TV, and adjust brightness to max while you are playing it (but readjust back down afterward!).